# Configuring Envoy proxy "retry" mechanism for gRPC service

Tags: go, grpc, envoyproxy, grpc-go

I am trying to configure Envoy proxy "retry" mechanism for a gRPC service written in Go. gRPC retries are currently only supported for gRPC status codes in response headers. Is there a way to send status codes in the header so that Envoy can intercept?

Comment: The gRPC library should handle delivering the status code appropriately (see https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc/status). Do you have a code example of what you believe should work and more about what you have tried?

Comment: @benjaminjosephw You are right that the error codes inside an error object are appropriately transmitted from gRPC Server to the Client. But Envoy Proxy requires the error codes to be sent inside a Response Header. I haven't been able to find a way to achieve this.

Comment: Just in case if you missed it, take a look at https://github.com/improbable-eng/grpc-web. Perhaps you'll be able to drop Envoy  layer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a listener that points to your extauth server, that listener will have a vhost with a retry policy (example 127.0.0.1 port 9000)

then create another cluster pointing to the listener created previously,for your extauth and use it for the extauth filter

so the call will go client -> listener -> extauth filter -> new listener with retry -> extauth service